# Netty ServerBootstrap - asynchronous binding?

Tags: asynchronous, jboss, bind, netty

First, here's a reference to where I read all of what I know now regarding this question:  http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html#bind%28%29

Although not explicitly specified by the documentation, it would seem that `ServerBootstrap.bind` is synchronous - because it does not return a `ChannelFuture`, but rather a Channel.  If that is the case, then I do not see any way to make an asynchronous bind using the `ServerBootstrap` class.  Am I missing something or will I have to roll my own solution?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own bootstrap implementation with the following addition:

```
public ChannelFuture bindAsync(final SocketAddress localAddress)
{
    if (localAddress == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("localAddress");
    }
    final BlockingQueue<ChannelFuture> futureQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<ChannelFuture>();
    ChannelHandler binder = new Binder(localAddress, futureQueue);
    ChannelHandler parentHandler = getParentHandler();
    ChannelPipeline bossPipeline = pipeline();
    bossPipeline.addLast("binder", binder);
    if (parentHandler != null) {
        bossPipeline.addLast("userHandler", parentHandler);
    }
    getFactory().newChannel(bossPipeline);
    ChannelFuture future = null;
    boolean interrupted = false;
    do {
        try {
            future = futureQueue.poll(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupted = true;
        }
    } while (future == null);
    if (interrupted) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Netty 3.6 there is an async bind.  Here's the javadoc:  http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html#bindAsync()